# Crear un almacenador de notas en un array a través de prompt()

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando crear un *array* que almacene números enteros. El caso es que tiene que pedir a través del `prompt()` 5 notas y almacenarlas.

Una vez estén almacenadas, debe mostrar a través de `console.log` el número de notas aprobadas y el número de notas suspendidas.

Estoy un poco atascado.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        

    
    function introCalificaciones()
    {
        

    var calificaciones = [];
    
    var caliIntro;

    for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) 
    {
        caliIntro = parseInt(prompt("Calificación:", ""));
        calificaciones.push(caliIntro);
    }

 
}

function mostrarResultados()
    {
        
         console.log("Hay "+calificaciones.filter(el => el >= 5).length+" aprobados");
         console.log("Hay "+calificaciones.filter(el => el < 5).length+" suspendidos");

       } 
             
               console.log(mostrarResultados());
  
        

        
    
    
    
    function main()
    {
        let calificaciones = introCalificaciones();
    }

    window.onload = main;
    

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿qué es exactamente lo que deseas hacer? ¿Indicar la cantidad de notas aprobadas y suspendidas?, ¿mostrar las notas aprobadas y suspendidas?, o ¿mostrar ambos?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

El cual nos devuelve otro array según un criterio, es decir

Si tengo este array de ejemplo

```
const myArray = [5, 10, 1 ,26 ,25, 20];
```

Y quiero obtener los elementos mayores a 15, se puede usar `myArray.filter`

```
console.log(myArray.filter(el => el > 15));
```

Resultado:

```
[26, 25, 20]
```

---

Entonces, en tu caso

```js
var calificaciones = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
  let caliIntro = parseInt(prompt("Calificación:", ""));
  calificaciones.push(caliIntro);
}

function mostrarResultados() {
    console.log("Hay "+calificaciones.filter(el => el >= 5).length+" aprobados");
    console.log("Hay "+calificaciones.filter(el => el < 5).length+" suspendidos");
}

mostrarResultados();
```

---

Con respecto a los comentarios:

El problema es que tienes dos funciones diferentes y `var` tiene alcance de función, es decir que la variable no será válida después de la función, lo que puedes hacer es juntar las dos funciones en una sola

```js
function introCalificaciones() {
  var calificaciones = [];
  var cont = "";
  var caliIntro;

  for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    caliIntro = parseInt(prompt("Calificación:", ""));
    calificaciones.push(caliIntro);
  }
  console.log("Hay "+calificaciones.filter(el => el >= 5).length+" aprobados");
  console.log("Hay "+calificaciones.filter(el => el < 5).length+" suspendidos");
}

introCalificaciones();
```

---

Con respecto a la edición de tu pregunta:

Considera añadir `return` a las funciones, pues si no devuelves nada solo devolverá `undefined`

```js
function introCalificaciones() {
    var calificaciones = [];
    var caliIntro;
    for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        caliIntro = parseInt(prompt("Calificación:", ""));
        calificaciones.push(caliIntro);
    }
    return calificaciones;
}

function mostrarResultados(calificaciones) {
    console.log("Hay " + calificaciones.filter(el => el >= 5).length + " aprobados");
    console.log("Hay " + calificaciones.filter(el => el < 5).length + " suspendidos");

}

mostrarResultados(introCalificaciones());
```

**Notas**

- El error de `calificaciones is not defined` era porque `var` tiene alcance de función (cosa que ya se explicó)
- Ese `window.onload` no es necesario, pues ejecutamos la función al inicio
- En `introCalificaciones` tienes que devolver `calificaciones` con `return`
- Para `mostrarResultados`, debemos eliminar el `console.log` y pasarle por parámetro el `return` que nos da `introCalificaciones`

Comment: Muchas Gracias! , no entiendo el punto en el que introducies ( el => el >=5) , a que hace referencia " el => el " , perdona pero estoy empezando...  pero creo que me falla algún parámetro de la función anterior para almacenar las notas introducidas por prompt() , no me da fallo pero no me muestra nada en la consola.

Comment: @RamiroMarinAguirre Es una [función flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions) la cual se usa en estos casos por su rapidez, lo que hace `filter` es recorrer cada elemento del array, tendremos que darle una función que devuelva un criterio que pongamos, al recorrer cada elemento del array, nos da como parámetro el elemento (por eso `el`)

Comment: Gracias por la explicación :) , pero no me muestra nada intentare arreglarlo.

Comment: @RamiroMarinAguirre Si estás poniendo el `console.log()` en una función debes de llamarla

Comment: Aún asi no me muestra los datos fuera de la funcion he puesto console.log(mostrarResultados); y me aparece esto por consola:ƒ realizarCalculos()
 {

         console.log("Hay "+calificaciones.filter(el => el >= 5).length+" aprobados");
      console.log("Hay "+calificaciones.filter(el => el < 5).length+" suspendidos");

Comment: @RamiroMarinAguirre Prueba con `console.log(mostrarResultados())`, sin los paréntesis te va a dar la función y no se va a ejecutar lo que está adentro

Comment: Me dice que no esta definido calificaciones en mostrarResultados , no esta cogiendo el array

Comment: Hola RamiroMarinAguirre, eso es porque no estás ejecutando la función `mostrarResultados()`. Es como te lo indicó @anythingg

Comment: @RamiroMarinAguirre ¿Te aseguraste de definir `calificaciones`? `var calificaciones = []`

Comment: He probado la solución de @anythingg y funciona. Por eso, la pregunta que te dejé sobre qué es lo que deseas hacer exactamente.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Me gustaria hacer dos funciones una en la que se solicite al usuario mediante prompt() la introducción de tres notas y una vez se guarden en el array , mostrar por consola el numero de suspensos y el numero de aprobados. Es decir si se introducen 5 6 5 1 el console.log deberia mostrar : Numero de aprobados : 3 y Numero de suspensos 1.

Comment: @anythingg si si , como ves en el código que he publicado la función introCalificaciones está definida , o tengo que definirla en la función mostrarResultados también? , ya estoy hecho un lio perdonad.

Comment: Pero eso es exactamente lo que hace la solución propuesta por esta publicación.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. acabo de editar mi post con el código que se me quedó después de la aportación de anythingg y no me funciona , tengo algún error?

Comment: @RamiroMarinAguirre Modifiqué mi respuesta, resolviendo todos los errores, debería funcionar ahora

Comment: @anythingg Ahora si !!!! muchas gracias por todo y disculpa las molestias... Muy amable!

Comment: @anythingg Una dudilla más si no es molestia ... como puedo evitar que siga preguntandome notas es decir una vez le introduzco 5 sigue pidiéndome mas